# Is it possible to list loads due to potential aliasing violations?

Tags: c++, c, gcc, optimization

I have been working on a sizeable performance critical code base, where compiling with the latest  versions of gcc give numerous warnings about type punning, leading me to compile with `-fno-strict-aliasing`. I don't believe there is any performance loss here that can be avoided anyway. I do however believe that there may be rather more significant issues with aliasing pointers of the same type.

Is there any way to get gcc, or any other tool to list all places in a code base where additional loads / stores are taking place due to potential aliasing violations that gcc can't detect, whether pointers are of the same type or not? That way, I could go compare with a code profiler and see if the situation can be improved in places where it actually matters by the use of `restrict`, local variables, refactoring etc. Trying to guess what the compiler is thinking through looking at generated assembler is both time consuming and error prone, particularly for this. I'm interested in answers for both C and C++ if they are different.

Comment: Seems to be safer to fix warnings due to strict-aliasing and don't use `-fno-strict-aliasing`.

Comment: Interesting question.  If GCC doesn't offer such a thing, you could also consider techniques using analysis of the generated assembly or machine code to at least check how different the results end up being.  I did something like that for two different sets of build options with GCC and discovered that for the settings I was testing there was virtually no difference at all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[GCC Debug options](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.0.0/gcc/Debugging-Options.html#Debugging-Options)

Try out -ftree-dump-alias (search for alias in above link).